# How to stub any instances for a given class using Rspec Mocks

Tags: ruby, mocking, rspec

The following code raises an error: `undefined method 'any_instance' for String:Class`

```
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
end

describe String do
  it 'stubs' do
    String.any_instance.stub(:foo).and_return(1)
    ''.foo.should eq(1)
  end
end
```

How can I include the Mocks module into the Class or Object class?

Answer (score 39):

any_instance was recently added to rspec, so your example now works for me as it is with rspec 2.7.

#### Update for rspec 3:

The new way to do this is

`allow_any_instance_of(String).to receive(:foo).and_return(1)`

Here is more any_instance documentation: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: Rspec Mocks 3.0 doc: [https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

Answer (score 3):

With RSpec Mocks in versions previous to 2.6.0, you cannot do it. However you can use `any_instance` with Mocha(as seen [here](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ClassMethods.html#M000001)) or in later versions of Rspec.

In your `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Make sure you have this line:

`config.mock_with :mocha`

uncommented.

Comment: Well, given that the question is "using Rspec Mocks", I'm not sure the answer "don't use Rspec Mocks" is useful. Then again, it's better than the technically correct answer: you can't do it.

Comment: The test above is actually a test from Rspec itself [link](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/spec/rspec/mocks/any_instance_spec.rb#L124). And the module AnyInstance gets included through (mocks.rb): 

`Class.class_eval  { include RSpec::Mocks::AnyInstance }`

I think there is a way to do it somehow.

Comment: That is the current master but hasn't been released yet. It will be part of the rspec-mocks-2.6.0 release, within the next week or two.

Comment: I am in 2.7.1 but have a similar issue too